# Count specific values of a row

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe with one row:

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
--------------------
0 4 2 4 1 3 2 1 1 3
```

I need for the code to count the number of same values in the row. So the output is:

1 = 3

2 = 2

3 = 2

4 = 2

Answer (score 1):

Use Series `value_counts()` method:

```
df.iloc[0, :].value_counts()
```

Answer (score 1):

transpose it (df.T) then use df.value_counts().

```
df.T.value_counts()
```

Answer (score 0):

Transform the column into a list and then:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([0 ,4 ,2 ,4, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3])
print([{i:list(df[0]).count(i)} for i in range(max(list(df[0]))+1)])
```

Output:

```
[{0: 1}, {1: 3}, {2: 2}, {3: 2}, {4: 2}]
```